# How to get Journey Entry DE Name using Postman Get Event Definitions

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, postman

I want to get journey Entry DE Name by using postman GET Event Definitions, and trying this url.
https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions?journeyId

But it fails to get my journey name.
It shows another journey. How to fix it?
[image]

this is my journey

Comment: What do you mean by “But it fails to get my journey name. It shows another journey.”?